# Setup secondary server for Transaction Log Shipping without connection to primary server

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, log-shipping

I'm having a hard time with SQL Transaction Log Shipping with the following premisses:

- Server A, where data gets loaded to the database
- Server B is on a remote location
- The two servers **never** share a common network and can communicate via common protocol. (HTTP, Email etc.)
- The internet connection on Server A is slow and only available a few times a month.
- I want to get data from Server A to Server B when an internet connection is available.

The idea i have so far is to make a Transaction Log Shipping setup on Server A and ship to Server B. I've got the setup running on Server A (Taking backups *n* times a day) but how do i set up Server B to accept the files i get to it (ATM via email)?

If the computers were in network, i could connect to Server B from Server A when making the TLS setup, and get the Server Agent Jobs setup like that. Is there a way to setup Server B separately? Write the Jobs directly on Server B sounds like an easy enough solution but the "Create New Job" dialog isn't very helpful.

Any other ideas or help in this matter is greatly appreciated!

Best regards
Niclas Lindqvist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a series of stored procedures that must be executed to setup log shipping on the secondary server.  Normally this is done by SQL Management Studio when you set up log shipping on the primary server.

This MSDN article should be what you need: [How to: Add a Secondary Database (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191308.aspx)

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your answer. Looks about right, and should solve Server B, but how can I setup the Server A without access to a secondary server?